# Error installing python-poppler-qt5 on Windows10

Tags: python, pip, poppler

I am trying to pip install pip install python-poppler-qt5, after working through many many errors I now recieve the error below: (I have poppler-0.68.0 in my program files and added to PATH).

```
pip install python-poppler-qt5
Collecting python-poppler-qt5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/7d/65a14ece5dd6a1564b576c1ca30b0f5639be64cc55b62b4d2b497159ed43/python-poppler-qt5-0.75.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: python-poppler-qt5
    Running setup.py install for python-poppler-qt5 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\zakorak\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Zakorak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jvte62kt\\python-poppler-qt5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Zakorak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jvte62kt\\python-poppler-qt5\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Zakorak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-s1i1y3_7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\Zakorak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jvte62kt\python-poppler-qt5\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Package poppler-qt5 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `poppler-qt5.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'poppler-qt5' found
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'popplerqt5' extension
    Package poppler-qt5 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `poppler-qt5.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'poppler-qt5' found
    C:\Users\Zakorak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\sip.exe -I C:\Users\Zakorak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\sip -t POPPLER_V0_20_0 -c build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release -b build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\poppler-qt5.sbf -I C:\Users\Zakorak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\sip\PyQt5 -n PyQt5.sip -t WS_WIN -t Qt_5_13_0 poppler-qt5.sip
    sip: Usage: sip [-h] [-V] [-a file] [-b file] [-B tag] [-c dir] [-d file] [-D] [-e] [-f] [-g] [-I dir] [-j #] [-k] [-m file] [-o] [-p module] [-P] [-r] [-s suffix] [-t tag] [-w] [-x feature] [-X id:file] [-y file] [-z file] [@file] [file]
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Zakorak\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\sip.exe' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\zakorak\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Zakorak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jvte62kt\\python-poppler-qt5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Zakorak\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jvte62kt\\python-poppler-qt5\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Zakorak\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-s1i1y3_7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have been stuck on installing python-poppler-qt5 for 2 days now and it is essential to my project, so any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should install poppler-qt5. I found a Windows binary [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/poppler-qt5-mingw32/).

Try installing it, but then you'll probably find other dependencies to be installed.

As I wrote on [Github issue](https://github.com/frescobaldi/python-poppler-qt5/issues/15#issuecomment-561978782), the best solution would be providing binary wheels for as many os/architectures as possible.